# Php echo inside if

Tags: php

There is a function I print it with echo Is it possible to write a condition in echo

Following my code:
`PHP`

```
$cart_count = WC()->cart->cart_contents_count; // Set variable for cart item count
$cart_url = wc_get_cart_url();  // Set Cart URL
echo '
    <div class="shopping-icons">
    <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
    <a href='.$cart_url.' ><span class="shopping-text">&nbsp;Sepetim</span></a>
       if ( '.$cart_count > 0 .')  { 
    <span class="cart-count-container">
    <span class="cart-count">'. $cart_count.'</span>
    </span>
     } 
    </div>
    ';
```

Comment: No, you need to leave echo. But you can combine it like so: `echo 'hello ', ($name ?: 'world'), '!';`

Comment: I did not fully understand the combination you said, could you please adapt it to my code?

Comment: @Ferhat means using ternary operator. Something like `echo '<div>' . (($cart_count > 0) ? '<span></span>' : '') . '</div>';`

Comment: yes the code worked thank you for your attention

Answer (score 1):

I mean... you could do what I do and just separate the echos...? lmao.

Not sure if this is wrong to do or what but I've been doing it like that for forever and it helps with easy maintenance plus it's easy to organize via tabs/spaces. Try not to facepalm too hard.. :-)

PS: Always try to use double quotes because it's easier to put in variables. With double quotes you can just put the variable in with a $ sign. You can't do that with single quotes, you'd have to use concatenation (like you did). TheMoreYouKnow.

---

```
echo "<div class='shopping-icons'>";
    echo "<i class='fas fa-shopping-cart'></i>";
    echo "<a href='$cart_url'><span class='shopping-text'>&nbsp;Sepetim</span></a>";
    if($cart_count > 0){ 
        echo "<span class='cart-count-container'>";
            echo "<span class='cart-count'>$cart_count</span>";
        echo "</span>";
    }
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: No problem. The ternary way works as well but this will accept any type of operation. You should still learn ternary and null coalescent methods, they are super useful for writing smaller info.